# Error in XML Parsing due to special characters

Tags: android

I am parsing an XML which has links with link tags. But it gives me an error because I think the link has special characters (Also I am using string replace function for "&").

Example link: http://tizentr.net/ara/linkler_tPEE9ZwTmy0.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace the special characters with their entity equivalents. for example:

```
> becomes &gt;
< becomes &lt;
& becomes &amp;
```

Comment: Hi srini, i replacing the & character in a php file. But problem is same.

Comment: Have you replaced, all possible entities? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references